# Is JavoNet a threadsafe library, and more imporantlty, does it allow usage of all threads?

Tags: javonet

Is javonet threadsafe? I couldn't find any documentation one way or the other. Even if it is threadsafe, is there some sort of "mutex" that's preventing full usages of all threads?

When I tried to run javonet in parallel, it did work, but the CPU usage did not significantly increase above the sequential load (ie on a 10CPU system, the CPU usage hovered around 20% for parallel load, whcih was only merely double the sequential CPU load of 10%); *however*, if I ran 10 version of the exact same sequential code (that used javonet), I achieved 100% CPU usage....so it "feels" like javonet must have some built-in mutexes that's preventing full parallel usage.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample reproduction code with which you observe the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javonet is thread safe.** You just need to follow standard practices for writing multi-threaded applications and Javonet will take care of executing your code properly.

Javonet creates new corresponding .NET thread for calling Java threads. Also the other way for callbacks, events and delegates if called from other thread Javonet will create the corresponding thread on Java side. Once the calling thread completes, Javonet will close the thread on the other side.

If the corresponding thread already exists, Javonet will rejoin to valid thread.

Javonet does use internal mutexes / readwritelocks while accessing objects instances, some caching collections and types what depending on your Java code might affect the parallelization capabilities.